# Using CASE in CHECK Constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I cannot get SQL Server to parse my query as I tried to alter a table and add a constraint.
like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TaxVal
ADD CONSTRAINT ch_taxVal CHECK (CASE WHEN Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN Col2 = 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

I want to update or set the value of col2 base on the value or condition of col1. Thank you

Comment: A check constraint cannot be used to update another column value

Comment: Checks are constraints,you need a trigger.